# Declaring a variable with a date found in sheet, issue

Tags: vba, date, excel, time

Currently I am trying to declare a variable as a date I pulled from a worksheet in excel, then use that declared date as a benchmark so I can delete everything greater than it. I think my code is solid for this task but the issue I keep having is when I look at what my date is declared as instead of being 1/12/2015 as it should it comes up at 12:00:00am and it replaces the contents of the cell in which I pulled the date from. Here is my code so far...

```
Sub Remove_Unecessary_Data_1()

Dim ALLCs As Worksheet
Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim Dailystring As String
Dim Blank As String
Dim finaldate As Date


Dailystring = " - Daily"
Blank = ""

Set DS = Sheets("Data Summary")
Set ALLCs = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")



    ALLCs.Select
        For y = 1 To 40
           If InStr(1, Allcs.Cells(13, y), "Timestamp of Execution") Then
                finaldate = Allcs.Cells(50, y)
            End If
        Next

    ALLCs.Select
        For u = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Allcs.Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
                For p = 2 To 69584
                If allcs.Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
                allcs.Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

I think the main issue herein lies that finaldate is being transforming into that odd time. Any ideas?

Also for reference the cell its pulling from 50,y reads

1/12/2015.

EDIT: I updated my code to reflect @freemans commented suggestion on the placement of my finaldate when trying to assign it a value. I had it reversed.

My new problem is the second part of my code doesn't accurately remove all of the dates necessary. For instance I need all of the dates about 1/12/15 removed, my program still does not do this, thought I don't see the error in my code

```
        ALLCs.Select
        For u = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Allcs.Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
                For p = 2 To 69584
                If allcs.Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
                allcs.Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

My issue lies here, why would 1/13/15 not be deleted if finaldate is declared as 1/12/15.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you with a working solution to the problem you posted. The procedure around here is to accept the answer that moved you forward, then ask another question when you run into a new issue. That's to avoid the possibility of making one question drag on for months while your whole program is debugged, but also to make it easier for someone to come along after you and find a good solution to **A** problem they're having without having to dig through a huge thread of edits. I'd recommend reverting your edit and starting up with a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare

```
Dim finaldate As Date
```

and you use it here

```
Cells(50, y) = finaldate
```

and here

```
            If Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
            Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
```

But you've never assigned a value **to** `finaldate`, therefore you're filling in a date/time of `0`. Any date value in `Cells([+14,u)` is highly likely to be greater than zero, therefore the row will be deleted.

Based on the comments below, try this updated code:

```
Sub Remove_Unecessary_Data_1()

Dim ALLCs As Worksheet
Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim Dailystring As String
Dim Blank As String
Dim finaldate As Date

Dailystring = " - Daily"
Blank = ""

'----------------------------Note this line:
finaldate = 'something! Today? Now? some user specified date? you don't tell us
'----------------------------

Set DS = Sheets("Data Summary")
Set ALLCs = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")

'ALLCs.Select     'to remove the possibility of future ambiguity, make the change below
For y = 1 To 40
    If InStr(1, AllCs.Cells(13, y), "Timestamp of Execution") Then
'note, you assign TO the left side of the equal sign (=) FROM the right side
        finaldate = AllCs.Cells(50, y)
    End If
Next

'ALLCs.Select
For u = 1 To 40
    If InStr(1, AllCs.Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
        For p = 2 To 69584
          If AllCs.Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
            AllCs.Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `finaldate` should be assigned to _something_. It depends on the needs of the program, which were not described. I'll update the answer to include something more specific.

Comment: Since I posted code, I also disambiguated the `Cells` reference. While the `AllCs.Select` line above does ensure you're on the right worksheet _now_, there's no guarantee that future code modifications will leave you there. By using `AllCs.cells()` instead, there's no chance of confusion in the future.

Comment: Yes but if the cells I'm referring to in Cells(50,y) are a date wouldn't that then make finaldate refer to that date permanently?

Comment: No, you would need to write `finaldate = Cells(50, y)`

Comment: Okay ALLCS is a static sheet, and therefore the date in that cell reference is constantly changing. So what I would like is for my program to pick up that date in the sheet and assign it the finaldate variable so I can compare it against other dates in my sheet.

so essentially no matter what I want 

   Finaldate = Allcs.Cells(50,y) 'the value that is in these cells.

Comment: @dom176, no, that line is setting `Cells(50,y)` **to** the value of `finaldate`, not setting `finaldate` to the value of `Cells(50,y)`. If `Cells(50,y)` contains the date you're looking for, then you need to reverse the order of the operators to this: `finaldate = AllCs.cells(50,y)`

Comment: @freeman If you can update your answer to now fix the second part of my question Ill accept it, thank you for the help.