# Piece of Code works as expected only when run multiple times

Tags: vba, date, excel, debugging

Currently I am debugging a piece of code. Currently my code works as intended it assigns a date of to the finaldate variable then looks in the code to delete all dates that are higher than the finaldate variable. Only problem is that the sub procedure needs to be run multiple times in order for this to take effect. For instance when I run through it once it removes about half of the dates, run through it again and it does the same, I usually F5 it about 5 times to confirm its complete. While this is fine in debugging I need to know this will work perfectly everytime.

```
Sub Remove_Unecessary_Data_1()

Dim ALLCs As Worksheet
Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim finaldate As Date




Set DS = Sheets("Data Summary")
Set ALLCs = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")



    ALLCs.Select
        For y = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Cells(13, y), "Timestamp of Execution") Then
                finaldate = ALLCs.Cells(50, y)
            End If
        Next

    ALLCs.Select
        For u = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
                For p = 2 To 69584
                If Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
                Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
  end sub
```

EDIT: Sample Data

Cells(50,y) = 1/12/15
finaldate = Cells(50,Y)

the column headed Start date contains dates that range anywhere from 1/05/15 to 1/30/15.

When working properly all dates after 1/12/15 should have their entire row eliminated.

Comment: Please can you provide a complete route and some sample data to support your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When deleting rows, you have to work your way from bottom to top, otherwise you end up skipping rows.

For example, you have:

```
 Line 1
>Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
```

When your code deletes, `Line 2`, what was "Row" 3 now becomes "Row "2, but you code moves on to see `Line 4`. Your data now looks like this:

```
 Line 1
 Line 3
 >Line 4
```

If you change this bit of your code:

```
For p = 2 To 69584
  If Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate Then
    Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
```

to this:

```
For p = 69598 to 16 step - 1
  If Cells(p, u) > finaldate Then
    Cells(p, u).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
```

Everything should be fine.

*Note: I adjusted your start & end points up by 14, and removed the `+ 14` from the `Cells()` reference. No sense in doing the extra math in there...

Comment: Also, remove the extra `.Select` statements as [R3uK mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29702690/2344413), and as I put in my solution to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29700743/2344413).

Comment: You're making my life a lot easier today @freeman thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a row using:

```
Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
```

the row below the deleted row moves up to occupy that space.  If that row contains a date that should be deleted it will be ignored because the counter automatically moves onto the next row. For example, say we wish to delete any rows with `C` or `D` in the `Data` column:

```
Row Number    Data
1             A
2             B
3             C    
4             D
5             E
```

becomes:

```
Row Number    Data
1             A
2             B
3             D
4             E
```

Tthe row counter moves onto 4 without checking the new value in 3 so the `D` will not be deleted.

You can solve this by changing your `If...Then` statement to a `Do...While` loop:

```
Sub Remove_Unecessary_Data_1()

Dim ALLCs As Worksheet
Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim finaldate As Date




Set DS = Sheets("Data Summary")
Set ALLCs = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")



    ALLCs.Select
        For y = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Cells(13, y), "Timestamp of Execution") Then
                finaldate = ALLCs.Cells(50, y)
            End If
        Next

    ALLCs.Select
        For u = 1 To 40
            If InStr(1, Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
                For p = 2 To 69584
                    Do While (Cells(p + 14, u) > finaldate)
                        Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
                    Loop
                Next
            End If
        Next
End sub
```

This should keep checking that cell after it has deleted the previous row to ensure the replacement row should not be deleted also.

Comment: You typed _just_ faster than I did!

Comment: Just going "backwards" is far more easier and will work for sure

Comment: @FreeMan Ha, sorry, the caffeine had just kicked in!

Comment: @R3uK I've never figured out whether it's faster to work upwards or just while loop over the row to keep checking.  I guess you're checking you're checking the same number of rows either way?

Comment: @stucharo, until you said that, I was thinking your solution was pretty good. _However_, if the data range you're checking doesn't go to the end of the used rows, you could end up deleting past where you wanted to stop. In this example, your method is going to delete to row 69584 whether that's in the valid data range or not. This is dangerous if you have 10,000 rows of data but only want to delete from the first 5,000 rows - you'll overrun your stop point. By starting at row 5,000 & going backwards, you know the precise range you'll impact.

Comment: @FreeMan Thx for your fast answer, I don't have to explain it!^^ Btw are you getting a hold on your PivotCharts?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you delete a row while going increasingly in row's number, you will miss to analyze every rows right after the one you just delete because it (rows(i+1)) has become the rows(i) and yet you increased with the next.

Here is your code taking that into account (and got rid of the useless `Select`)

```
Sub Remove_Unecessary_Data_1()

Dim ALLCs As Worksheet, _
    DS As Worksheet, _
    FinalDate As Date

Set DS = Sheets("Data Summary")
Set ALLCs = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")

For y = 1 To 40
    If InStr(1, ALLCs.Cells(13, y), "Timestamp of Execution") Then
        FinalDate = ALLCs.Cells(50, y)
    End If
Next


For u = 1 To 40
    If InStr(1, ALLCs.Cells(13, u), "Start Date") Then
        For p = 69584 To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(p + 14, u) > FinalDate Then
            Cells(p + 14, u).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```